# Capture behave outputs into a dynamically created log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

I am trying to capture the Behave outputs in a file(let's say a log file). I am  dynamically creating a new log file at '@then' step for every run of Behave based on datetime. Below is the sample code given in the steps/xx.py file.

```
def filecreation(filename):
    chwd=os.chdir('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\features\\test_features')
    with open(filename, 'w+') as d:
        pass

cur_ts = datetime.datetime.now()
log_time_stamp = str(cur_ts).split('.')[0].replace(' ',':').replace('-',':').replace(':','')
file_name = 'ATMorFrameRelay' + log_time_stamp + '.log'
filecreation(file_name)
pass
```

Now i am trying to send the Behave output at every run to the log file created above. I am aware that the command "Behave -o [file name]" will create a file for every run , but thought will rather send the STDOUT to the above created file for every new run. Also is it fine/safer to use the STDOUT to write into files in a production like environment and not cause any issues.

I am a newbie to both Python and Behave, so looking forward for any solution/suggestions on how it can be achieved. Any relevant materials or information will be really appreciated too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't explain why exacly are you trying to do it. And no, there is nothing wrong to use `-o filename` in production (and it doesn't use stdout, it replaces stdout with filesrteam). Heck behave even support output formats way more suitable for further parsing like `--juni`

Comment: I am trying to capture the behave outputs in a dynamically created file on every run of Behave. The above given code is just for file creation, and with "behave -o", the file name has to be mentioned explicitly, so not willing to use it. Just need some leads/ideas for routing the be\have outputs to the dynamically created file rather than to the STDOUT.

Comment: I did give you one. Instead of rewiring the whole steps just rewire your test runner to use random name provided to -o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this, where `cmd` is actually behave command to run the tests.

```
cmd = [
    'behave',
    '--no-capture',
    '--no-capture-stderr',
    '--format', 'progress2',
    '--logging-level', 'INFO',
    '--no-source', '--no-skipped', '--no-summary',
    '--tags', 'MACRO'
    ]
with io.open(filename, 'a') as writer, io.open(filename, 'rb', 1) as reader:
   process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=env, stdout=writer,stderr=writer)
   while process.poll() is None:
        sys.stdout.write(reader.read())
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
   sys.stdout.write(reader.read())
   sys.stdout.flush(
```